# What's the difference between 'my' and 'our' in Raku?

Tags: scope, raku

Furthermore, what criteria should inform your use of one over the other?

---

I found a few SO answers/comments ([1][2][3]) that *mostly* answer the title's question, however I thought it nicer to have it in a single place. The question was inspired by a similar one in [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845060/10824322).

- [1] [What is the difference between my class and our class in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790925/10824322) (*title redacted*)
- [2] [Using modules to load a group of related functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45771170/10824322)
- [3] [is export and binding in Raku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874426/10824322) (*title redacted*)