# Symbols Created in Stash at Runtime Not Available in PseudoStash in Raku

Tags: scope, eval, raku, scoping

This question started with me trying to figure out why symbols created at runtime are not available to `EVAL`.

**outer-EVAL.raku**

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;

package Foobar {
  our $foo = 'foo';

  our sub eval {
    say OUTER::;
    EVAL "say $bar";
  }
}

Foobar::<$bar> = 'bar';
say $Foobar::bar;

Foobar::eval;

.say for Foobar::;
```

```
$ ./outer-EVAL.raku 
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /development/raku/VTS-Template.raku/scratchpad/./outer-EVAL.raku
Variable '$bar' is not declared
at /development/raku/VTS-Template.raku/scratchpad/./outer-EVAL.raku:10
------>     EVAL "say ⏏$bar";
```

I *think* it has to do with the fact that symbols created this way don't appear to be available in `PseudoStash`s. But I could be wrong.

**outer.raku**

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

package Foobar {
  our $foo = 'foo';

  our sub outer {
    say OUTER::;
  }
}

Foobar::<$bar> = 'bar';
say $Foobar::bar;

Foobar::outer;

.say for Foobar::;
```

```
$ ./outer.raku 
bar
PseudoStash.new(($?PACKAGE => (Foobar), $_ => (Any), $foo => foo, &outer => &outer, ::?PACKAGE => (Foobar)))
&outer => &outer
$bar => bar
$foo => foo
```

As you can see, `$Foobar::bar` is in the `Foobar::` `Stash`, but not in the `OUTER::` `PseudoStash`. So, my question is twofold: why are symbols created at runtime not available to `EVAL`, and why are symbols created at runtime not available to `PseudoStash`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## When is an answer a nanswer?

While I'm happy I've written this, I'm unsatisfied with it *as an answer to what I've concluded is the heart of your question*, namely *why* there's no way to get `EVAL` to violate the principle that lexical symbols are frozen during compilation.

Aiui the rationale boils down to A) avoiding dangerous security loopholes, and B) it not being considered worthwhile allowing for violation under some `MONKEY` pragma.

But whether that's accurate, and discussing that, and any possibilities a Rakudo plugin could enable violating the lexical principle, is far beyond my paygrade.

I'm tempted to copy this answer into a gist, link to it from a comment on your question, and delete this answer.

Alternatively, if you agree there's this gaping hole in my answer, perhaps you'd be so kind as to unaccept it, and then I can put a bounty on it to try get an answer from jnthn, and/or encourage others to answer?

## Quick fixes

1. Add a package qualifier:

   ```
   package Foo {
     our sub outer {
       EVAL 'say $Foo::bar'  # Insert `Foo::`
     }
   }

   $Foo::bar = 'bar';
   Foo::outer; # bar
   ```

or:

2. Use a *lexical* (compile-time) symbol:

   ```
   package Foo {
     our $bar;          # Create *two* symbols *bound together*
     our sub outer {
       EVAL 'say $bar'  # Use *lexical* symbol from *lexical* stash
     }
   }
   $Foo::bar = 'bar';   # Use *package* symbol from *package* stash
   Foo::outer;          # bar
   ```

   (It might help to read the opening part (up to "so: `our $foo = 42;` Is doing this: `(my $foo := $?PACKAGE.WHO<$foo>) = 42;`") of [jnthn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874426/1077672) to a fairly unrelated SO question.)

## Initial answers to your questions

> why are symbols created at runtime not available to `EVAL`?

They *are* available.

But:

- Symbols created at run-time can only be created within some existing or new symbol table hash (aka "stash"<sup>**[1]**</sup>) (which stash must have some symbol naming it, which symbol in turn can only be created within some existing or new stash, and so on recursively);
- The stashes for such symbols must be *package* stashes (using the built in `Stash` type), not *lexical* stashes (which use the `PseudoStash` type).
- Any reference in code to a *package* symbol must name the enclosing package(s) as part of that reference.

So, for example, given a `$foo::bar = 42;` statement declaring a symbol `$bar` at run-time in a package `foo`:

- A `$bar` symbol would be added to a package stash (`Stash`) associated with the package `foo`;
- The package `foo`, and its associated stash, would in turn be created if it did not already exist, along with a symbol `foo` being added to the existing package stash corresponding to the package containing the `$foo::bar = 42;` statement.

And then, to refer to the `$bar` symbol you would have to write `$foo::bar` (or use one of the other forms of package qualified references such as `foo::<$bar>`). You are not allowed to refer to it as just `$bar`.

---

> why are symbols created at runtime not available to `PseudoStash`s?

The built in `PseudoStash` type is used by the language/compiler to stash *lexical* symbols at *compile-time*.

---

For discussion of the rationale for this distinction between *lexical* and *package* scopes/symbols/stashes (and complications such as the `our` declarator's use of both; and the fact one can create *lexical packages*), see the answers to [What is the difference between `my class` and `our class`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788788/what-is-the-difference-between-my-class-and-our-class-in-rakuperl6).

## All about *stashes*

There are two built in stash types:

- **[`PseudoStash`](https://docs.raku.org/type/PseudoStash)s are for *lexical* stashes** The language/compiler adds (static) *lexical* symbols<sup>**[2]**</sup> to lexical stashes at compile-time. User code can only indirectly modify lexical stashes using language constructs that do so as part of their operation (eg `my $foo` and `our $bar` both add a lexical symbol to a lexical stash).
- **[`Stash`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Stash)s are for *package* stashes** The language/compiler adds *package* symbols (at compile-time or run-time) to package stashes during compile-time or run-time. User code can add, delete or modify package stashes and package symbols.

## *Lexical* stashes

These are managed by the language/compiler and frozen at the end of compilation.

---

You can *add* whole new lexical stashes, and add to existing lexical stashes, *but only by using language constructs under the language's precise control* such as:

- A `{ ... }` lexical scope. This will lead the compiler to create a new lexical stash corresponding to the scope.
- `package Foo {}`, `use Foo;`, `my \Foo = 42;` etc. The language/compiler will, as part of compiling these statements, add a symbol `Foo` to the lexical stash corresponding to the innermost lexical scope containing such a statement. (For the first two it will also create  a new *package* stash and associate that with the value of the `Foo` symbol. This stash will be accessible via `Foo.WHO` or `Foo::`.)

---

You can *refer* to lexical stashes, and the symbols within them, by using various ["pseudo-packages"](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages)<sup>**[3]**</sup> such as `MY`, `OUTER`, `CORE`, and `UNIT`.

---

You can *assign* or *bind* to an *existing* symbol in these lexical stashes using pseudo-packages associated with lexical stashes:

```
my $foo = 42;
$MY::foo = 99;    # Assign works:
say $foo;         # 99
$MY::foo := 100;  # Binding too:
say $foo;         # 100
```

But that's the only modification you can do. You cannot otherwise modify these stashes, or the symbols they contain:

```
$MY::$foo = 99;          # Cannot modify ...
BEGIN $MY::foo = 99;     # Cannot modify ...
my $bar;
MY::<$bar>:delete;       # Can not remove values from a PseudoStash
BEGIN MY::<$bar>:delete; # (Silently fails)
```

---

`EVAL` insists that *unqualified* symbols (no `::` within the reference, so references like plain `$bar`) are *lexical* symbols. (For the rationale, see the SO I linked near the start.)

## *Package* stashes

Package stashes are created by the language/compiler as needed according to user code.

---

Like lexical stashes, you can refer to package stashes via some "pseudo-package" names.

| This... | refers to the *package* stash associated with... |
| --- | --- |
| `OUR::` | the scope in which the `OUR` appears |
| `GLOBAL::` | the interpreter |
| `PROCESS::` | the process in which the interpreter is running |

---

Symbols can be added to package stashes due to the *implicit* meaning of language constructs such as an `our` declaration:

```
our $foo = 42;
```

This adds a `$foo` symbol to both the *lexical* stash corresponding to the innermost enclosing lexical scope, and a *package* stash corresponding to the scope:

```
say $foo;      # 42  (Accesses `$foo` symbol in enclosing *lexical* stash)
say $MY::foo;  # 42  (Same)
say $OUR::foo; # 42  (Accesses `$foo` symbol in enclosing *package* stash)
```

---

Unlike lexical stashes, package stashes are modifiable. Continuing on from the code above:

```
OUR::<$foo>:delete;
say $OUR::foo; # (Any)
$OUR::foo = 99;
say $OUR::foo; # 99
```

All of which leaves the *lexical* stash untouched:

```
say $foo;      # 42
say $MY::foo;  # 42
```

---

Package stashes can also be added due to the implicit meaning of user code:

```
package Foo { my $bar; our $baz }
```

Without a scope declarator (eg `my` or `our`) ahead of the `package` declarator, `our` is assumed. Thus the above code would:

- Create a new `Foo` symbol;
- Install two copies of that `Foo` symbol, one in the *lexical* stash corresponding to the innermost enclosing lexical scope (accessible via `MY::`), and the other in the *package* stash corresponding to the scope (accessible via `OUR::`);
- Create a new *package* stash, and associate that with the `Foo` type object, accessible by writing `Foo::` or `Foo.WHO`.

So now this will hopefully make sense despite any initial surprise:

```
package Foo { my $bar; our $baz }
say  MY::Foo;        # (Foo)
say OUR::Foo;        # (Foo)
say  MY::Foo::.keys; # ($baz)
say OUR::Foo::.keys; # ($baz)
```

The value of the `Foo` symbol in the `MY` *lexical* stash is exactly the same as the one in the `OUR` *package* stash. That value is bound to another *package* stash as accessed via `Foo.WHO` aka `Foo::`.

So `MY::Foo::.keys` and `OUR::Foo::.keys` list the same symbols, namely just `$baz`, which is in the `Foo` package's stash.

You *don't* see `$bar` because that's in the *lexical* stash which corresponds to the same surrounding scope as the `Foo` package but is nevertheless a distinct stash. More generally, you *can't* see `$bar` from *outside* that braced code because a key Raku design element is that the user and compiler can rely on purely lexically scoped symbols being 100% encapsulated due to their lexical nature.

---

Whereas you can't even *see* any *lexical* symbols from outside their lexical scope, you can not only see but *modify* any *package* symbols from wherever you have access to the symbols corresponding to their enclosing packages:

```
package Foo { our sub qux { say $Foo::baz } }
$Foo::baz = 99;
Foo::qux; # 99
```

---

A line like `$Foo::Bar::Baz::qux = 99;` will if necessary autovivify any non-existing package stashes, which can then be seen using a package stash reference such as the pseudo-package `OUR`<sup>**[4]**</sup>:

```
$Foo::Bar::Baz::qux = 99;
say OUR::Foo::.WHAT;           # (Stash)
say OUR::Foo::Bar::.WHAT;      # (Stash)
say OUR::Foo::Bar::Baz::.WHAT; # (Stash)
say $Foo::Bar::Baz::qux;       # 99
```

---

`EVAL` will happily use symbols added at run-time provided references to them are suitably qualified:

```
package Foo { our sub bar { say EVAL '$OUR::baz' } }
$Foo::baz = 99;
Foo::bar; # 99
```

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> They're called "stashes" because they're **s**ymbol **t**able h**ash**es.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> The abstract concept "symbol" is implemented as [`Pair`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Pair)s stored in stashes.

<sup>**[3]**</sup> The term "pseudo-packages" is perhaps slightly unfortunate because a couple of them are aliases of `Stash`s rather than `PseudoStash`s.

<sup>**[4]**</sup> For references like `Foo::Bar`, which do not start with a sigil but do contain a `::`, you need to ensure you adhere to Raku's rules for resolving such references. I'm still working out what those are precisely, and intend to update this answer when I've got that nailed down, but I've decided to post this answer as is in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, @raiph! I guess it's not possible to EVAL non-qualified symbols. I wonder if it is possible with NQP?

Comment: @JustThisGuy I've completely rewritten my answer. Please consider unaccepting this answer for the reasons given at the start, unless you really, truly are fully satisfied with it. You can always re-accept it later if nothing else comes along and you prefer not to leave the question open. I for one would love to see jnthn at least briefly discuss why there's no `MONKEY` pragma for making `EVAL` more evil.

Comment: @JustThisGuy Having (hopefully, mostly) put this (n)answer to bed, I went to read reddit, and found gfldex had written [this](https://gfldex.wordpress.com/2021/08/24/dynamic-declaration/), showing how someone with sufficient MOP chops can fairly easily bend the meaning of package declarators (like jnthn's `actor`). I dunno if down that path lies a solution to your situation, or madness, or both, or neither, but gfldex's conclusion is "I once believed Raku to be less dynamic then Perl. Looks like I have to reconsider.", and their Raku wizardry is way ahead of my Mickey Mouse Fantasia Moves!

Comment: Thanks again! I unaccepted for now. I should have time to re-read your answer tomorrow, and I'll check out that reddit post. That comment about Raku being less dynamic is interesting, since trying to port some Perl code to Raku is what set me down this path. I too would be interested to find out if there has been any thought put into making ```EVAL``` more evil. :)